# Get custom term meta problem on single post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, metabox

I'm trying to display a custom field value added to custom taxonomy on single custom post type. I have articles post type with custom taxonomy called issue. I used the code from [Tax-Meta-Class](https://github.com/bainternet/Tax-Meta-Class)  to add custom field "publication date" to that taxonomy. For each issue I added a "publication date" value. To display the publication date of the child issue on each related single article I tried to use this code:

```
$object_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'issue', array( 'fields' => 'all' ) );
if ( $object_terms ) {
    foreach ( $object_terms as $term ) {
        if ( $term->parent ) { 
            $t_id .= $term->term_id;
            $res .= get_tax_meta($t_id,'publication_date'); 
        }
    }
    echo $res;  
}
```

But nothing is displayed. I also tried to use `get_term_meta` instead of `get_tax_meta` but got nothing.
If I added `echo $t_id;` It displays the term ID which means that the code can correctly get the term ID but it fails to display the custom field value.
Any help please?

Comment: Where did you get the `get_tax_meta()` and `get_term_meta()` functions from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here what I did & finally problem is solved.
To make the code work just use `get_term_meta` and add `true` to be like this:

```
    $res .= get_term_meta($t_id,'publication_date',true);
```

I hope this will help any one facing such issue. Also, those who use prefix need to add it before the field name as mentioned by P-S

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions:

1. Check if there's a **prefix** which you setup for the custom field (https://en.bainternet.info/tax-meta-class-faq/#comment-1107)
2. Go to the **Tax-meta-class/Tax-meta-class.php** file and find the function you're calling and debug the issue:

   ```
   // Tax-meta-class.php

   public function get_tax_meta($term_id,$key,$multi = false){
       $t_id = (is_object($term_id))? $term_id->term_id: $term_id;
       var_dump ($t_id); // debug this

       $m = get_option( 'tax_meta_'.$t_id);
       var_dump ($m); // debug this

       if (isset($m[$key])){
            return $m[$key];
       }else{
           return '';
       }
   }
   ```
3. Check the ***wp_options*** table and search the ***option_name*** column for the option (the parameter of ***get_option('tax_meta_foo_bar')*** above). It's either not there or you're missing the prefix for ***get_option*** not to return a value.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer. I tried option 1 & 2 but no results. I searched for what you said in wp_options & I didn't find it. what I should do please?

Comment: please see how i fixed the problem with my answer below.